# Unable to connect peer to channel in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am following below link to setup my first network on Hyperledger Fabric
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html

Whatever steps are mentioned in this setup i am pretty much able to do all.
The issue is than when I try to join other peers to the channel, using below instruction

> You can make other peers join the channel as necessary by making
>   appropriate changes in the four environment variables.

I export following variables

```
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:8051
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
```

and then I run

```
peer channel join -b mychannel.block
```

I get below error

```
2017-08-02 06:38:12.375 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2017-08-02 06:38:12.376 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2017-08-02 06:38:12.379 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 003 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 172.19.0.2:8051: getsockopt: connection refused"; Reconnecting to {peer1.org1.example.com:8051 <nil>}
2017-08-02 06:38:13.379 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 004 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 172.19.0.2:8051: getsockopt: connection refused"; Reconnecting to {peer1.org1.example.com:8051 <nil>}
2017-08-02 06:38:15.085 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 005 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 172.19.0.2:8051: getsockopt: connection refused"; Reconnecting to {peer1.org1.example.com:8051 <nil>}
Error: Error getting endorser client channel: PER:404 - Error trying to connect to local peer
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/common/common.go:116 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/common.GetEndorserClient
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel/channel.go:149 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel.InitCmdFactory
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel/join.go:138 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel.join
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel/join.go:42 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel.joinCmd.func1
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:599 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:689 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:648 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/main.go:118 main.main
/opt/go/src/runtime/proc.go:192 runtime.main
/opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2087 runtime.goexit
Caused by: context deadline exceeded
Usage:
  peer channel join [flags]

Flags:
  -b, --blockpath string   Path to file containing genesis block
```

org1 peer0 I was able to connect but not other nodes

Docker ps output

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think maybe the port's problem.

You set

`export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:8051`

While peer listen on 7051, therefore you need to change CORE_PEER_ADDRESS to

`export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7051`.

Comment: Thanks.. this worked but i am not able to under stand that why is it not connecting through 8051 as it is the exposed port. May be need to read the docker documentation on this.

Comment: The 8051 is a port mapping in case you would like to access container from your laptop, while inside docker network, e.g. peer cli it remains 7051 and 8051 no accessible since no one listens on that port.

Comment: in case still there is issue . i have used  real hostname:port. That worked for me like sd-1234-see.com:7051

Answer (score 0):

This is problem of port.
Now how to decide which port to be given.

Check your configtx.yaml file.

```
 AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org2.example.com
              Port: 9052
```

Same port we need to pass below.

```
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:9052
```

Now run `peer channel join -b mychannel.block`

If still any issue you can mail me on ActAchieveRepeat@gmail.com.
Thanks